# Rownum order is incorrect after join - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, rownum

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/97fbe/1 - fiddle

I have tried to demo my real life scenario as much as possible

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [OrderTable] 
(
    [id] int,
    [OrderGroupID] int,
    [Total] int,
    [fkPerson] int,
    [fkitem] int

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 

INSERT INTO [OrderTable] (id, OrderGroupID, Total ,[fkPerson], [fkItem]) 
VALUES
  ('1', '1', '20', '1', '1'),
  ('2', '1', '45', '2', '2'),
  ('3', '2', '32', '1', '1'),
  ('4', '2', '30', '2', '2'),
  ('5', '2', '32', '1', '1'),
  ('6', '2', '32', '3', '1'),
  ('7', '2', '32', '4', '1'),
  ('8', '2', '32', '4', '1'),
  ('9', '2', '32', '5', '1');

CREATE TABLE [Person] 
(
    [id] int,
    [Name] varchar(32)

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 

INSERT INTO [Person] (id, Name) 
VALUES
  ('1', 'Fred'),
  ('2', 'Sam'),
  ('3', 'Ryan'),
  ('4', 'Tim'),
  ('5', 'Gary');

CREATE TABLE [Item] 
(
    [id] int,
    [ItemNo] varchar(32),
    [Price] int

    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) 

INSERT INTO [Item] (id, ItemNo, Price) 
VALUES
  ('1', '453', '23'),
  ('2', '657', '34');
```

Query:

```
WITH TABLE1 AS 
(
    SELECT 
        -- P.ID AS [PersonID], 
        -- P.Name, 
        SUM(OT.[Total]) AS [Total], 
        i.[id] AS [ItemID],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rownum,
        ot.fkperson,
        [fkItem]
    FROM 
        OrderTable OT
    -- INNER JOIN Person P ON P.ID = OT.fkperson
    INNER JOIN 
        Item I ON I.[id] = OT.[fkItem]
    GROUP BY 
        -- P.ID, P.Name,
        i.id, ot.fkperson, [fkItem]
)
SELECT 
    t1.[fkperson],
    P.[Name],
    t1.[itemid],
    t1.[total],
    t1.[rownum]
    -- Totalrows = (SELECT MAX(rownum) FROM TABLE1)
FROM 
    TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN 
    Person P ON P.ID = T1.fkperson
INNER JOIN 
    Item I ON I.[id] = T1.[fkItem]
```

Result:

```
| fkperson | Name | itemid | total | rownum |
+----------+------+--------+-------+--------+
|        1 | Fred |      1 |    84 |      1 |
|        3 | Ryan |      1 |    32 |      2 |
|        4 |  Tim |      1 |    64 |      3 |
|        5 | Gary |      1 |    32 |      4 |
|        2 |  Sam |      2 |    75 |      5 |
```

which is the result I want. However, my real-life example is giving me the row number in a weird order. I know its an issue with a join because when i comment these join:

```
INNER JOIN 
    Person P ON P.ID = T1.fkperson
INNER JOIN 
    Item I ON I.[id] = T1.[fkItem]
```

out it works fine.

```
| fkperson | Name | itemid | total | rownum |
|----------|------|--------|-------|--------|
|        1 | Fred |      1 |    84 |      4 |
|        3 | Ryan |      1 |    32 |      3 |
|        4 |  Tim |      1 |    64 |      5 |
|        5 | Gary |      1 |    32 |      1 |
|        2 |  Sam |      2 |    75 |      2 |
```

Has anyone got any advice on how the join would be causing these weird rownumber ordering? Or point me in the right direction. Thanks

Comment: Your `ORDER BY` in your `ROW_NUMBER` is `ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)`. That's like saying "It doesn't matter what order you put these in, just give them a number". Use a "proper" `ORDER BY` clause. This is much like asking why the order of your data isn't in date order when you haven't included an `ORDER BY` in the query.

Comment: Worse, you've specifically said "use any ordering you feel like" then complained its not in the order you want

Comment: @Larnu Explain how it orders correctly by rownum in my first query even though it uses select null

Comment: @RyanGadsdon That's called Co-incidence.  It just so happens that the execution plan generated by the first query does nothing that would change the ordering of the dataset.  But that is expressly ***not*** guaranteed to happen every time.  Next time you run it it's likely to be the same, run it again tomorrow it's still likely to be the same, but it is never ***guaranteed*** to behave that way.  What would you "expect" to happen if you had two different calculations for columns `rownum1` and `rownum2`?  ***ONLY*** an `ORDER BY` guarantees the order.

Comment: @RyanGadsdon with data from a small table, with no other tables involved *normally* the order the data is returned is consistant, but just like Matbailie said, it isn't guaranteed, it's more blind luck (as the data engine just so happened to do the task and read the data in exactly the same way each time). I have a lot tables where if i were to perform a .`SELECT TOP 10 * FROM [Table];` i would get a different result almost every time (and yes it has a Clustered index on it). That's for the same reason, without an `ORDER BY` the data engine just returns 10 rows, the "first 10 it found".

Answer (score 3):

Any relational database is **inherently UNordered** - and you won't get any guaranteed order **UNLESS** you explicitly ask for it - by means of an `ORDER BY` clause on your outer query.

You need to add the `ORDER BY` explicitly - like this:

```
WITH TABLE1 AS 
(
    .....
)
SELECT 
    (list of columns ....)
FROM 
    TABLE1 T1
INNER JOIN 
    Person P ON P.ID = T1.fkperson
INNER JOIN 
    Item I ON I.[id] = T1.[fkItem]
ORDER BY 
    T1.rownum
```

Comment: so this will always be un-ordered unless i specifically state to use order by? In my other scripts it automatically orders via rownum without having to use order by

Comment: @RyanGadsdon Regarding your `other scripts`; No, it doesn't.  It "just so happens, by chance" that it comes out in the same order.  The first line of this answer is correct, without an `ORDER BY` a dataset is inherently unordered.  All sorts of factors can cause your `other scripts` to stop behaving in the way you anticipate : index fragmentation, concurrent users, spilling to disk, changes to server configuration, etc, etc.  If you ***need*** the order to be ***guaranteed*** you absolutely ***must*** specify an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: The only reason i question this ordering is because this is the only script i have the issue with and this is the only script that joins outside of the CTE so i assumed that was having some affect on the ordering

Comment: @RyanGadsdon It is, internally to the database's engine.  Look at the execution plans.  It has to "do stuff" to accomplish your joins.  Will that change the ordering, maybe, maybe not, it depends on factors out of your control.  The database will do what it needs to do to accomplish what your write in your query.  If you don't specify an `ORDER BY` it will make no effort to preserve any particular ordering (as doing so may make other operations more expensive).  I say this one last time...   If you ***need*** the order to be ***guaranteed*** you absolutely ***must*** specify an `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `order by (select null)`.  That means *indeterminate ordering*.  And the order can change from one invocation of the query to another.

You should not be depending on default ordering, even by an external `order by`.  If you want values in a particular order, specify that ordering *explicitly* in the `order by` in the windowing clause.

Comment: No ordering?  Arbitrary order?

Comment: in my real example, even if i over (order by [column]) it still has rownum unordered

Comment: @MatBailie . . . "no ordering" is more accurate I think.  The ordering is not "arbitrary" (which suggests a certain amount of randomness); it is indeterminate.  We simply do not know what the engine will do.